# Android SIP Framework : Playing background music

Tags: android, sip

Using the Android SIP framework (WalkieTalkie Sample), does anyone know if you play background music in the call?

I know you can for PJSIP but thats extremely hard to implement (well I think it is).

I have tried setting up a call and then playing music via MediaPlayer however this just played it normally (as expected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, looking around I do not believe it was possible, in the end I went back to PJSIP and contacted their support on how to use it with Android.  Their support rocks